# Llimit count of data reads per user firebase and firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am developing an application that provides business reports hosted on an AWS virtual machine to registered users through Firebase with a user profile in Firestore. Each time the user makes a query, the number of queries increases in his Firestore profile (code attached). I would need that users can not make more than 10 daily queries .. how can I do it?

code :

```
child: FlatButton(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Text(
          'Process',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          final FirebaseUser user =
              await _auth.currentUser();

          var loginSuccess = await model
              .getdata(_inputCuit.text);
          if (loginSuccess) {
            
            Firestore.instance
                .collection("users")
                .document(user.uid)
                .updateData({
              "queries": FieldValue.increment(1)
            });

            
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'post',
                arguments: model.info);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UxOp.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in security rules to limit the number of reads a user makes. If that is a requirement for your use-case, you'll have to implement the reads in Cloud Functions or some other trusted environment.